# How do I input multiple values that are comma-separated into a table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, import-from-csv

Disclaimer: I am completely new to PHP and MySQL/SQL.

I have multiple `implode()`functions for my arrays. I want to be able to have the arrays input into the table separated with commas to avoid confusion.

```
  $company_state = implode($_POST['companystate']);
```

The output looks like this in the table and when `echo`:

`Company state:
ILMEMDNVOHOK`

But I want it to look like this within the table:

`Company state:
IL, ME, MD, NV, OH, OK`

Is there any way I can get it to do this?

Here is the code for the form:

```
<label for="companystate[ ]">Company state:</label><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="AL"  /><strong>Alabama</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="AK"  /><strong>Alaska</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="AZ"  /><strong>Arizona</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="AR"  /><strong>Arkansas</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="CA"  /><strong>California</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="CO"  /><strong>Colorado</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="CT"  /><strong>Connecticut</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="DE"  /><strong>Delaware</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="DC"  /><strong>District of Columbia</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="FL"  /><strong>Florida</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="GA"  /><strong>Georgia</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="HI"  /><strong>Hawaii</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="ID"  /><strong>Idaho</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="IL"  /><strong>Illinois</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="IN"  /><strong>Indiana</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="IA"  /><strong>Iowa</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="KS"  /><strong>Kansas</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="KY"  /><strong>Kentucky</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="LA"  /><strong>Louisiana</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="ME"  /><strong>Maine</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="MD"  /><strong>Maryland</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="MA"  /><strong>Massachusetts</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="MI"  /><strong>Michigan</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="MN"  /><strong>Minnesota</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="MS"  /><strong>Mississippi</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="MO"  /><strong>Missouri</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="MT"  /><strong>Montana</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="NE"  /><strong>Nebraska</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="NV"  /><strong>Nevada</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="NH"  /><strong>New Hampshire</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="NJ"  /><strong>New Jersey</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="NM"  /><strong>New Mexico</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="NY"  /><strong>New York</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="NC"  /><strong>North Carolina</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="ND"  /><strong>North Dakota</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="OH"  /><strong>Ohio</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="OK"  /><strong>Oklahoma</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="OR"  /><strong>Oregon</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="PA"  /><strong>Pennsylvania</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="RI"  /><strong>Rhode Island</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="SC"  /><strong>South Carolina</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="SD"  /><strong>South Dakota</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="TN"  /><strong>Tennessee</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="TX"  /><strong>Texas</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="UT"  /><strong>Utah</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="VT"  /><strong>Vermont</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="VA"  /><strong>Virginia</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="WA"  /><strong>Washington</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="WV"  /><strong>West Virginia</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="WI"  /><strong>Wisconsin</strong><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="companystate[ ]" value="WY"  /><strong>Wyoming</strong><br />
```

Thanks in advance. And also could you explain to me what each function does? I'm still learning and most of PHP/SQL is still gibberish to me.

Comment: With all due respect, you probably *don't* want to insert the value "IL, ME, MD, NV, OH, OK" into your table.  Rather, it would usually be much, much better to insert 6 rows (with one each for IL, ME, MD, NV, OH and OK):  http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Comment: You shouldn't have that space in `name="companystate[ ]"`. It should be `companystate[]`, even if it works with your current PHP version. Also, normalization, while advisable for performance, might not be needed. CSV is sort of supported in MySQL - with `FIELD_IN_SET()` able to query your column.

Comment: Thank you for your tip, Paul. I will consider it for future projects.

Comment: Thanks, Mario. I'll fix that now. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass in some glue for your implode:

```
implode(', ', $_POST['companystate']);
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple. I was puting a period instead of a comma to separate `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$company_state = implode(",", $_POST['companystate']);
```